# Can I use Google Translate API for Arabic language for long term in android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, arabic-support

I want to use [Google Translate API](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts) for TTS in arabic language. Currently it is working fine but does it create any problem in future and how much I can trust on this api for my application? If anyone know its limitations please let me know.

[this](https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=%22your%20text%22&tl=ar&client=tw-ob) is my Request url

Answer (score 0):

Android is indeed supported the Arabic language since version 2.3; So, you have to choose version 2.3 as the minimum target, lower version won't supported Arabic.

Comment: Yes i know that i just want to know reliability of this api for specially arabic language.